# Row reducing this matrix... I can't ever seem to do these problems.

Tags: linear-algebra

$$\qquad
  \pmatrix{1&0&2&4\cr0&1&-3&-1\cr3&4&-6&8\cr0&-1&3&1}\ .$$

I have to do this by hand, and I know what the final solution is. But intuitively looking at this, how would I know how to rref this matrix?

Comment: Subtract three times the first row from the third row to get started.

Comment: Look at what would happen if you add row two to row four. That is the type of cancellation you should look for.

Comment: Solution such a problem is exactly equivalence to "just starting to solve" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all you need to do:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 1 & -3 & -1 \\ 3 & 4 & -6 & 8\\ 0 & -1 & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 1 & -3 & -1 \\ 0 & 4 & -12 & -4\\ 0 & -1 & 3 & 1\end{bmatrix}\sim\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 2 & 4\\ 0 & 1 & -3 & -1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, can you see what row operations were performed to reach the matrix on the right-hand side?